# Search any keyword in range of cells and fetch all the cells address as it's result if that keyword found in it

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, with-statement

```
Function FindValueInCellRange(MyRange As Range, MyValue As Variant) As String
    With MyRange
         FindValueInCellRange = .Find(What:=MyValue, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), 
         LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
         SearchDirection:=xlNext, 
         MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, 
         ColumnAbsolute:=False)
    End With
End Function
```

With the above code, I was trying to search any given keyword in the range of cells that I select and fetch all those cells address as it's result if that particular keyword is found in it.. but now it is only fetching the very first cell, but not all the cells. I want all the cells as my result where that word is being found in the given range. Kindly help me with this one on how I can get that as my result.

& Also please suggest instead of it's cell address, if we want that particular cell's header names as our result.. how can we get that. Kindly advise.

Comment: The addresses of cells are a piece of pretty useless information. Also, if the length of the resulting string exceeds 255 characters, you won't be able to use it in one go. What should the result look like? A comma-separated string? Could you share what you are planning to do with this result? It would be more useful to combine the found cells into a range where this limitation wouldn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function FindCells(ByVal searchRange As Range, ByVal keyword As String) As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim result As String
    
    For Each cell In searchRange
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, keyword, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            result = result & "," & cell.Address(False, False)
        End If
    Next cell
    
    If Len(result) > 0 Then
        result = Mid(result, 2)
    End If
    
    FindCells = result
End Function
```

Also, maybe a formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("keyword",A1:D10)),ADDRESS(ROW(A1:D10),COLUMN(A1:D10)),""))
```